# Django Paypal Client/Server Data doesn't seem to come to server

Tags: python, django, paypal

I use this implementation for frontend:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

my frontend in particular:

```
............
// Call your server to set up the transaction
          createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return fetch("/createOrder", {
              method: "post",
              credentials: "same-origin",
              headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
              },
            })
              .then(function (res) {
                console.log("res");
                console.log(res);
                return res;
              })
              .then(function (orderData) {
                console.log("orderData");
                console.log(orderData);
                return orderData.id;
              });
          },
......................
```

My backend:

```
def sth(request):
    logger.error('called')
    t = gettoken()
    d = {"intent": "CAPTURE","purchase_units": [{"amount": {"currency_code": "USD","value": "100.00"}}]}
    h = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer "+t}
    r = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', headers=h, json=d).json()
    logger.error(r)
    return r
```

Python console (logger.error(r)):

```
{'id': '597275692P0354804', 'status': 'CREATED', 'links': [{'href': 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/597275692P0354804', 'rel': 'self', 'method': 'GET'}, {'href': 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=597275692P0354804', 'rel': 'approve', 'method': 'GET'}, {'href': 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/597275692P0354804', 'rel': 'update', 'method': 'PATCH'}, {'href': 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/597275692P0354804/capture', 'rel': 'capture', 'method': 'POST'}]}
```

My errorcode in Frontend

```
Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed
```

For me it looks like the response doesn't reacht my frontend. Do i missed something?

Comment: inspect source, switch to network tab and click the url that matches... and look at preview it will show you what is returned ...

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is, that i call the function after it passed some other files. So the respond is to the last file and not to the first one. Have to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your middle section to

```
.then(function (res) {
            console.log("res");
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
          })
```

you might also need to wrap it in a response

probably `JSONResponse` but i think in this case a normal `HTTPResponse` is sufficient

in python

```
return HTTPResponse(content=json.dumps(r))
```